# Query Access with single table to calculate previous Basket results database

Tags: ms-access, subquery

I must do a query on an Access 2010 DB to extract previous points results for each team.

I have a single table with history match results on Basket

```
The table is like this :
Table Name = History
ID Auto Increment
Date : datetime
Host : text
Guest: text
HostPoint:integer
GuestPoint:inetger
```

The table data is like this :

```
1     01/02/2015     BARCELONA     REAL MADRID     105  80
5     25/01/2015     BARCELONA     LAS PALMAS      65   73
7     24/01/2015     BARCELONA     JUVENTUS        80   75
10     15/01/2015    VALENCIA      REAL MADRID     101  120
11     14/01/2015    TOLEDO        REAL MADRID     101  100
15     14/01/2015    BARCELONA     PSG             105  60
18     11/01/2015    GALA          REAL MADRID     101  70
```

I want to generate a table or query with for each record, the min and max result for each team on the previous 3 match at home for host and away for guest.

The table is like this :

```
Table Name = HistoryResult
ID Auto Increment
Date : datetime
Host : text
Guest: text
HostPoint:integer
GuestPoint:inetger
MinHostHomePoint:integer
MaxHostHomePoint:integer
MinGuestAwayPoint:inetger
MaxGuestAwayPoint:inetger
```

**Example, for the first record the result must be this :**

```
1     01/02/2015     BARCELONA     REAL MADRID     105  80    65  105   70  120
5     25/01/2015     BARCELONA     LAS PALMAS      65   73    80  105   0   0
7     24/01/2015     BARCELONA     JUVENTUS        80   75   105  105   0   0
10     15/01/2015    VALENCIA      REAL MADRID     101  120  0    0     70  100
11     14/01/2015    TOLEDO        REAL MADRID     101  100  0    0     70  70
```

I think that I must use Alias and also Subquery, but I have tried different solution with resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the following;

```
SELECT History.ID, History.MatchDate, History.Host, History.Guest, History.HostPoint, History.GuestPoint, qryHomeMinMaxPoints.MinOfPoints AS MinHostHomePoint, qryHomeMinMaxPoints.MaxOfPoints AS MaxHostHomePoint, qryAwayMinMaxPoints.MinOfPoints AS MinGuestAwayPoint, qryAwayMinMaxPoints.MaxOfPoints AS MaxGuestAwayPoint FROM (History INNER JOIN (SELECT Team, Min(Points) AS MinOfPoints, Max(Points) AS MaxOfPoints FROM (SELECT MatchDate, Team, Points FROM (SELECT History.MatchDate, History.Host AS Team, History.HostPoint AS Points FROM History)  AS qryHomeMatches WHERE MatchDate In  (SELECT TOP 3 MatchDate  FROM   ( SELECT History.MatchDate, History.Host AS Team, History.HostPoint AS Points FROM History )   as qryHomeMatchesCopy  WHERE qryHomeMatchesCopy.Team = qryHomeMatches.Team  ORDER By MatchDate DESC))  AS qryHomeLastThree GROUP BY Team)  AS qryHomeMinMaxPoints ON History.Host=qryHomeMinMaxPoints.Team) INNER JOIN (SELECT Team, Min(Points) AS MinOfPoints, Max(Points) AS MaxOfPoints FROM (SELECT MatchDate, Team, Points FROM (SELECT MatchDate, Guest AS Team, GuestPoint AS Points FROM History)  AS qryAwayMatches WHERE MatchDate In  (SELECT TOP 3 MatchDate  FROM   ( SELECT MatchDate, Guest AS Team, GuestPoint AS Points FROM History )  as qryAwayMatchesCopy  WHERE qryAwayMatchesCopy.Team = qryAwayMatches.Team  ORDER By MatchDate DESC))  AS qryAwayLastThree GROUP BY Team)  AS qryAwayMinMaxPoints ON History.Guest=qryAwayMinMaxPoints.Team;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, but it give me an error : Syntax Error on FROM Clause on the last :

GROUP BY Team)

Comment: Check the field names and parenthesis, the following link contains sample file with the query working fine: http://1drv.ms/1MilZYH

Comment: Thanks this workes fine !
But with my database, is very very slow, also filtering only a today match, it take more than an hour tu run :(
And I need to run it for a whole month